# Cannot install Oracle Virtual Box 6.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, oracle

I installed some weeks ago  Oracle Virtual Box 6.1 to Ubuntu 20.04.1 without
any problems.
Since 10 January 2021 I have tried to install it to to my backup  computer
with the same configuration but it does not work.
I have followed many instructions I have found with Google, but without success.

**My conclusion is that something has been updated in Virtual Box or Ubuntu since my
last installation which makes the VB broken.
Has anybody else this problem with installing  Oracle Virtual Box 6.1 to Ubuntu 20.04.1  and know how to solve it?**

As my last trial I tried the official VB page instructions on
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
and I followed "Debian-based Linux distributions"
by using "focal" in "mydist"

But when I try to open a new box I get error:

---

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

---

I tried : sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

But I got a serie of other and errors and tried to solve with Google, but they are too long to describe.

Comment: Disable secure boot.

Comment: Why not use the default repository version?  It's 6.1 too.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds related to the 5.8 kernel issues.

If you boot into the latest working 5.4 kernel it will work.

Several bugs have been reported on the issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu?field.searchtext=virtualbox+kernel